# Extract and plot time vs. date from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I've read a CSV into a Pandas `df`. Here's a description of the column I'm interested in:

```
df['datetime'].describe()

count                     810
unique                    691
top       2018-04-22 08:15:00
freq                        8
first     2018-02-10 10:15:00
last      2018-12-18 11:32:00
Name: datetime, dtype: object
```

What I want to do is plot that timestamp. Simple right?

I want to plot the date along the x-axis and time (24H) along the y-axis.

How do I do it?

I was thinking of something like:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from datetime import datetime
TOOLS="hover,crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,zoom_in,zoom_out,box_zoom,undo,redo,reset,\
    tap,save,box_select,poly_select,lasso_select,"
p = figure(width=500, height=500, x_axis_type="datetime", y_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS)

df = pandas.read_csv('./logs.csv')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
xvalrange = pandas.date_range(start=df.iloc[-1]['datetime'].strftime('%Y/%m/%d'), end=\
                      df.iloc[0]['datetime'].strftime('%Y/%m/%d'), freq='D')
yvalrange = pandas.date_range(start='00:00:00', end='23:59:59', freq='60min').time
```

It's incomplete. This:

```
p.circle(df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'),\
         df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'),\
         alpha=0.5)
```

Generates a graph that clearly is not correct. And:

```
p.line(xvalrange,yvalrange,\
   alpha=0.5)
```

Also clearly isn't correct either.

So. How do I plot the just %Y-%m-%d on x-axis and %H:%M:%S on y-axis?

EDIT:

If switch the above code starting at `xvalrange` for the following code:

```
xvals = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
yvals = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

p = figure(title="Test Title", width=500, height=500, \
           x_axis_type="datetime", y_axis_type="datetime", \
           x_range=(df.iloc[-1]['datetime'].strftime('%Y/%m/%d'),\
                    df.iloc[0]['datetime'].strftime('%Y/%m/%d')),\
           y_range=('00:00:00','23:59:59'),\
           tools=TOOLS)
p.line(xvals, yvals, alpha=0.5)
show(p)
```

This also does not produce a graph, just a blank graph.

Comment: @tripleee. No, this is about plotting a graph. The other question wasn't.

Comment: @uncle-junky might not be ideal but converting the datetime column to separate columns might solve the issue.

Comment: @sid I thought about doing that, but what's the point when the column's value is a full timestamp? Should be able to just extract the separate parts for each axis from the single value.

Comment: @uncle-junky I honestly don't know, but it should be an error in the split date and time command. May be try to see the output of date and time split in console and see if you can spot the problem?

Comment: @sid I updated the code in the question based on your feedback. It returns a blank graph. Am I asking the question in the right way? Just want to plot date along one axis, and the corresponding time on the other.

Comment: Try `p.line(df['datetime'].dt.date, df['datetime'].dt.time, alpha=0.5)`?

Comment: @KenSyme Yes that gets me somewhere, but is it possible to set the range manually on the x-axis (date)? A continuous 365 days of 1 day intervals?

Comment: @uncle-junky Unfortunately I am not familar with bokeh to know how to do that - [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/8lgVFOzot68) might help?